# Error assigning to a Range: Wrong number of arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through named worksheets creating a pdf from each sheet and saving it to a folder.

Have so far created the below and its getting stuck saying wrong number of arguments.

It gets stuck at '3 Pages If Range("B16") = "3 page Statement" Then Range - it then says

> "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Using Win 7 and Excel 2010

```
Sub CreatePDFs_Click()
' CreatePDF_Statements
'

' Create a PDF from the current sheet and save to folder

Dim DestFolder As String, PDFFile As String
Dim OpenPDFAfterCreating As Boolean, AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean, DisplayEmail As Boolean
Dim OverwritePDF As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet_name As Range

'Loop
For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Info").Range("A:A")
If sheet_name.Value = "" Then
Exit For
Else
Sheets(sheet_name.Value).Select

ws.Activate

    OpenPDFAfterCreating = False    'Change this if you want to open the PDF after creating it : TRUE or FALSE
    AlwaysOverwritePDF = False      'Change this if you always want to overwrite a PDF that already exists :TRUE or FALSE

DestFolder = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("M4")


    'Customer Name stored in B8
    CustomerName = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value, InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value, " ") + 50)

    'Create new PDF file name including path and file extension
    PDFFile = DestFolder & Application.PathSeparator & CustomerName & ".pdf"

    'If the PDF already exists
    If Len(Dir(PDFFile)) > 0 Then
        If AlwaysOverwritePDF = False Then

            OverwritePDF = MsgBox(PDFFile & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")

            On Error Resume Next
            'If you want to overwrite the file then delete the current one
            If OverwritePDF = vbYes Then
                 Kill PDFFile
                     Else

                MsgBox "OK then, if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill PDFFile
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then

            MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'Create the PDF
'0 Page

    If Range("B16") = "0   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

    End If

'1 Page

    If Range("B16") = "1   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

    End If

'2 Pages
    If Range("B16") = "2   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50,K2:R50").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

    End If

'3 Pages
    If Range("B16") = "3   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

    End If

'4 Pages
    If Range("B16") = "4   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50,AC2:AJ50").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

    End If

'5 Pages
    If Range("B16") = "5   page Statement" Then

    Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50,AC2:AJ50,AL2:AS50").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating


    End If

          Cancel = True


        End If

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you slim it down to just the relevant section and the line throwing the error?

Comment: It gets stuck at '3 Pages
    If Range("B16") = "3   page Statement" Then

    Range - it then says "Wrong number of arguments or invalid properrty assignment" Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Distilling the error message...

> "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

... the problem is that you are trying to pass 3+ arguments to `Range`, which can at most take 2. You want to combine each different area within a *single* range reference.

Change

```
Range("B2:I50", "K2:R50")
...
Range("B2:I50", "K2:R50", "T2:AA50")
...
Range("B2:I50", "K2:R50", "T2:AA50", "AC2:AJ50")
...
Range("B2:I50", "K2:R50", "T2:AA50", "AC2:AJ50", "AL2:AS50")
```

to

```
Range("B2:I50,K2:R50")
...
Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50")
...
Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50,AC2:AJ50")
...
Range("B2:I50,K2:R50,T2:AA50,AC2:AJ50,AL2:AS50")
```

Comment: Thank you evry much for your input, I have made the corrections but as a novice I'm getting a new error message at the end saying "For without next" - could you advise further please

Comment: You're probably missing an End If

Comment: No, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59179665/edit) your *question*

Comment: I HAVE IMOVED: ws.Activate
FROM UNDER: DestFolder = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("M4")
TO  UNDER: Sheets(sheet_name.Value).Select
And removed the last:    End With

Comment: Click this link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59179665/edit - and edit your original question with your code, please, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, have just updated it. Error says for without next now

Comment: Yes, because you have a `For` but no `Next`. Check out this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to indent your code properly.

Comment: Wow thats good, was not aware of this - still have message For but no Next though?

Comment: You still have a `For`, but no `Next`. There's no `Next` to close the `For Each sheet_name In Sheets("Info").Range("A:A")` loop.

Comment: Sorry I'm just not understanding this. What I am trying to achieve is to create a pdf from a sheet range and save it to a folder and then do the same on all subsequent sheets in the specified range (Col A on 'Info' sheet) and then stop when it reaches a sheet with no value in cell B8 - Sorry for not grasping this

Comment: When you have a `For` loop, it needs to be closed with a `Next`. You have the `For` portion, but you don't have a `Next`. Add the `Next` to close the loop.

Comment: Have tried various attempts like  Next ws but just ca't get this right

Comment: `Next sheet_name`, or just `Next`.

Comment: I really appreiate you helpand guidance but I think I need help with the whole code / challenge as I now have an ELSE without an IF